# Bash set -e not exiting immediately with pipefail

Tags: bash, shell, exit-code

```
set -eo pipefail

commandThatFails || exitFunction

exitFunction
```

So this script is running the exitMethod twice...  I thought `set -e` exited immediately on any non zero exit code and `set -o pipefail` made sure that during the pipeline any failure is the final exit status code not the most recent command?

Therefore I thought :

1. commandThatFails
2. Executes exitFunction
3. set -o pipefail returns non zero exit code as the first command fails
4. Non zero exit code is detected by set -e and exits immediately

In the docs it states:

> The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the
> command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of
> the test in an if statement, part of any command executed in a && or
> || list except the command following the final && or ||, any command
> in a pipeline but the last, or if the command’s return status is being
> inverted with !. If a compound command other than a subshell returns a
> non-zero status because a command failed while -e was being ignored,
> the shell does not exit. A trap on ERR, if set, is executed before the
> shell exits.

I thought that the exitfunction is the `command following the final ||` so therefore would be counted and picked up and exited immediately.

I can resolve the issue with:

```
commandThatFails || { exitFunction; exit 1; }
```

but it doesn't seem like the more elegant way to handle this, any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: See [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises). `set -e`'s behavior is wildly unintuitive and unportable (even between different versions of bash). It makes code harder to review, and more likely to behave differently between shell versions; is not generally recommended for use.

Comment: (https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/ is another reference, showing just how many ways shells can implement `set -e` differently)

Comment: One other misunderstanding here is that `foo | bar || baz | qux` is one pipeline. It's _two_; `foo | bar` is one, and `baz | qux` is the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`||` is a flow control operator, not a pipeline component. `pipefail` has no effect on it.

If `set -e` caused flow control operators to exit, then you could never have an `else` branch of your script run with it active; it would be completely useless.

For that reason, `&&` and `||` suppress `set -e` behavior for their left-hand sides, just like `if condition; then success; else fail; fi` suppresses that behavior for `condition`.

---

General practice is to make your `exitFunction` *actually call `exit`*, so you can write:

```
die() {
  rc=$?
  (( $# )) && printf '%s\n' "$*" >&2
  exit "$(( rc == 0 ? 1 : rc ))"
}

commandThatFails || die "commandThatFails failed"
```

...but if you want to call something else first, yes, you need to use a grouping, just as you did in the question.

Comment: Brilliant! Wasn't clued up on the definitions.  Makes a lot more sense now. Cheers!